# $_POST is empty (script works locally, not online)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter.

I have written a code, that allows user to register on my page. 
I have tested it locally (XXAMP) and it worked. Than I uploaded the files.

Unfortunately, the script no longer works. The $_POST variable remains empty.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('Start/register/'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Benutzername" name="username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" name="password" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" name="passwordr" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email-Adresse" name="email" type="email" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input name="agbaccept" type="checkbox" value="agb"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Start/agb'); ?>">AGB's</a> gelesen und akzeptiert
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Registrieren">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

From Comment

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How do you know that the `$_POST` variable is empty?

Comment: I have debugged it:

Comment: echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: issues like this generally is caused by server misconfigurations. which server you use? have you configured any 301 or 302 redirects?

Comment: This is my .htaccess-File:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: You can put your code in code boxes in the comments. Use your tilda key to do so, as shown in the information below this box. It will make it a lot easier for us to see the config code.

Answer (score 0):

Load `url` and `form` helper and then try as below:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open(base_url('start/register/')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Benutzername" name="username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" name="password" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" name="passwordr" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email-Adresse" name="email" type="email" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input name="agbaccept" type="checkbox" value="agb"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Start/agb'); ?>">AGB's</a> gelesen und akzeptiert
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Registrieren">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

also set

```
$config['base_url']='your domain name';
```

Comment: That doesn't help anything.
Because the base_url is already set. 
The form and url helper are already in the autoload.php.